# curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, curl

I want to run the following on ubunt 20.04:

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon
```

what I got is this:

```
sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  4046  100  4046    0     0  16782      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   98k
downloading Nix 2.5.1 binary tarball for x86_64-linux from 'https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-2.5.1/nix-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.xz' to '/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.KPhkYw21Nn'...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.KPhkYw21Nn/nix-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.x
Warning: z: No such file or directory
  0 27.1M    0  1103    0     0  10753      0  0:44:05 --:--:--  0:44:05 10813
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
/dev/fd/63: failed to download 'https://releases.nixos.org/nix/nix-2.5.1/nix-2.5.1-x86_64-linux.tar.xz'
```

When I have a look at `/dev/fd/` I see a bunch of files marked inaccessible:

[image]

I guess this has something to do with the failure to download. Am I right? What can I do against it? I am just a 'normal' ubuntu user, this kind of stuff exceeds my ubuntu-knowledge.

UPDATE:
Even if I run the whole thing as root the result remains the same:

[image]

Comment: Probably you have to download inside your home folder, where you have enough permissions. Also note that /dev/fb/ and /dev/fd/ are different objects. Which guide do you follow? Do you have sudo permissions on this computer?

Comment: Try adding the option `-s` to curl. Maybe then you will notice this: "Warning: Failed to create the file"   and "Failure writing output to destination" .

Comment: @N0rbert, yes, I do have sudo permission, but id does not seem to help. I am trying to follow this : https://nixos.org/download.html. Forgive me for my stupid question, but I am now in pr@server (probably due to a earlier installation which no longer matters).From here how to get to get  to pr@home, or home?

Comment: @Luuk sh <(curl -s -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon 
Unfortunately makes no difference

Comment: You can enter `exit` to exit from SSH session. Or simply open new local terminal instance with Ctrl+Alt+T.

Comment: @N0rbert Unfortunately it's permanent. A new terminal also takes me to pr@server. Even after reboot.

Comment: You can try the "Installing from a binary tarball" which is mentioned in this document: [Installing a Binary Distribution](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/installation/installing-binary.html).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

After a very long research I found a useful hint.

[Can't write to a hidden path using Curl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356327/cant-write-to-a-hidden-path-using-curl)

Basically *snap* curl is useless. Uninstall it properly. Get the proper *apt* curl, and everything works like a charm.

```
$ sudo snap remove curl
$ sudo apt install curl
```

Comment: Great advice.  One problem though for me: I'm on ubuntu 22.04 and I removed snap curl. Problem is the alias 'curl' seems to remain and I have to manually type /usr/bin/curl if i want to use the apt installed version. Anyone know how to remove the snap curl alias?

Comment: @jb1,  I don't know why its still considering snap installed curl. But I suggest you to take a look inside "environment" file with `sudo vi /etc/environment`. And see how does the value of **PATH** variable looks like.

Precisely, "**/usr/bin**" should appear first, and later "**/snap/bin**" should present. Mine looks like this.

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: Same here when running `pyenv install` under Ubutnu 22.04.1. Resolved following your advice.

Comment: this problem still exist in ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Snaps strike again! What a POS...

Comment: Same problem, same solution: Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: I literally don't understand this at all.. but this fixes it.

Comment: I think the issue is related to how the snap store installs the command in the system. It seems like it's not correctly elevating the permission of the curl command itself when installing. So this is causing for some installation with directories like home in the ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case

```
$ sudo snap remove curl
```

didn't worked. So I had to remove it via apt-get like these:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove curl
```

Than installed it again.

```
$ sudo apt install curl
```

My problems solved.

Comment: If snap remove did not work it was not a snap that was installed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and below I shared how to fix.

First notice either you're logged-in as `root@your-server-ip` user or some other `user@ip` like `debian@your-server-ip` account.

In my case, I was logged-in as `debian@vps-1a7c9` and try to run command using `sudo` and without sudo but got error `curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination`

**How to Fix**:
run command `sudo su` to login as root
this will change the current user to root user and terminals will look like `root@your-server-ip`.

Even this user `debian@your-server-ip` is an administrator account, but terminal return curl error, and after changing it to `root@` all errors gone and commands worked. Means you're required to login as root.

Comment: The question says: `UPDATE: Even if I run the whole thing as root the result remains the same` It seems like you haven't read it.