# Right After piping to "head"/"tail": "curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination"

Tags: curl, pipe

When I curled a too long API call and wanted to show only the first 30 lines in the console with `curl my_api_call|head -30`, I ran into:

```shell
 24 49931   24 12089    0     0    98k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   99k
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

This is surely the same thing going on as in [curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387141/curl-23-failure-writing-output-to-destination), but there, it fails with the download. Here, it fails right after piping to "head"/"tail". The piping itself still works, I get the 30 lines. If I take the pipe out, there is no failure.

The answer of the other question could not help me, I ran `sudo apt remove curl` and `sudo apt install curl`.

What to do to get rid of the failure? Up to now, I do nothing, that is already working well. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Found workaround

I was able to suppress the error message `curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination` with following command line:

`RESPONSE=$(curl http://httpstat.us/502); head -n 1 <<< $RESPONSE`

### The steps in detail

1. Tell `curl` to write the full content into a variable (which prevents the error message from curl). If you like, you could also check for error codes after this step.
2. Forward the variable to `head`

Answer (score 1):

As per my analysis, the error might be reasonable if the head command cuts off some data or it can display the full result.

I checked with `curl http://www.google.com | head -n 10 && echo "Success" || echo Failure` (=partial contant) and with `curl http://www.google.com | head -n 1000 && echo "Success" || echo Failure` (=full content) and I always get `curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination` in case of the 10-lines variant. The 1000-lines variant always executes without this error message.

Interestingly, my test shows "Success" in both cases.
Also `(curl http://www.google.com | head -n 10); echo $?` always shows an error code `0` in the end.
BUT: my GitLab pipeline somehow detects that this command failed and shows my gitlab-job as failed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, curl apparently checks if it fails to write to stdout.

`$ man curl` type `/^ +-S` and hit enter, then read a couple lines beyond that and you'll find an option that is likely to be useful for you. (i.e. `--silent` )

If you still wish to see the 30 first lines; redirect output to a a file in /tmp/, then do a `head -n 30` on that file.