Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop (RPi) - cannot add repository
I am trying to add the 45Drives repos to my Raspberry Pi Ubuntu install so I can use their Cockpit extensions. When I try to run the command, I get this error saying that curl can't write its downloaded files.
jaherron@littlebit-pi5:~$ sudo curl -sSL https://repo.45drives.com/setup | sudo bash
[sudo] password for jaherron: 
Detected Debian-based distribution. Continuing...
There were no existing 45Drives repos found. Setting up the new repo...
Updating ca-certificates to ensure certificate validity...
Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [3590 B]
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble InRelease                           
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-updates InRelease [89.7 kB]
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports noble-security InRelease
Fetched 93.3 kB in 1s (82.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version (20240203).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gcc-14-cross-base libc6-amd64-cross libgcc-s1-amd64-cross libstdc++6-amd64-cross
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
Failed to download the new repo file. Please review the above error and try again.


please use the search before asking questions. topic with your error as a title with an accepted answer:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387141/curl-23-failure-writing-output-to-destination

Your question mentions 23.04 or the 2023-April release; that was lunar in codename... I've changed your question to be about 24.04 (or the 2024-April release) as I see mention of noble or the codename of 24.04 in your question.
